# Choco Error: Initial Propagation: Contradiction due to

Tags: java, constraint-programming, choco

I use `Choco` and when I try to solve a model, I get the message:

```
- Initial Propagation: Contradiction due to [48.89604359598426,4.0]
```

What does that mean? I could not find it in documents.

Comment: It means that the model has no solution, I guess. For example, if you try to find real `X` such as `X * X = -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Sarge Borsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1418097/sarge-borsch) suggested in comments, it happens when there is a contradiction between one or more constraints and the solution space. The first number is the only solution found for a decision variable. The second number indicates that user imposed the variable to be that number.

Therefore, for instance, three solutions for `x` are `6`, `9` and `10` but if there exists a constraint `x < 0`, that contradicts with the solutions found and the solver backtracks all the way back.

Which means, there are no solutions for the model.

Comment: Please consider deleting both the question and the answer. It is not helping anybody.

Comment: @Ali I edited the question. It might be helpful now.